# Spark: Creating a RDD from a REST service

Tags: apache-spark

Is there any out-of-the box functionality in Spark available to bind an RDD to a REST service? That is, calling a web service and get an RDD.

Or is the simplest approach to call the rest service by myself and convert the result collection to a RDD ?

Thanks.

Comment: Found anything on this? I am looking for something similar where I would like to use Spark SQL on my Web Service returned JSON data.

Comment: Did not investigate this further, but I guess just do it yourself (create a wrapper)...think it is not so difficult to do so...

Answer (score 0):

I used jersey client, read a string (one comple json document per line), and with this string did this:

```
val stringResponse = request.request().get(classOf[String])
val jsonDataset = session.createDataset[String](Seq(stringResponse))
// try with case class
val parsedResponse = session.read.json(jsonDataset)
```

...which results in a DataFrame that you can select stuff on.

Answer (score -2):

You can refer to the link [Spark-Jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver)

Some of the features of Spark-Jobserver which I think you are looking for are :

- "Spark as a Service": Simple REST interface for all aspects of job, context management
- Start and stop job contexts for RDD sharing and low-latency jobs; change resources on restart
- Asynchronous and synchronous job API. Synchronous API is great for low latency jobs!
- Named RDDs to cache and retrieve RDDs by name, improving RDD sharing and reuse among jobs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP is looking for a way to read web service data into Spark as an RDD.